# Show a hidden div when the user scrolls down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that sticks to the top of the page when you scroll past it.
When this navbar is fixed to the top of the page, I would like a logo to appear.
The logo is inside the div #navlogo.

I currently have #navlogo set to display: none. I am thinking that when you scroll past 100px its display will need be set to display block or something similar.

I have tried a few things but i'm not very good at java and had no luck.

[You can check out the JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/gx25ospo/2/)

This is the script I'm using to set my navbar to fixed

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var nav = $('#custom-bootstrap-menu');
    var body = $('body');
    var top = 100;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= top) {

        nav.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        body.addClass('padding-fifty');

    } else {
        nav.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        body.removeClass('padding-fifty');
    }
});
```

and a little css

```
#logo {
    height: 100px;
}

.padding-fifty {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#navlogo {
    display: none;
}
```

As you can see it sets the nav to fixed, and compensates the page offset by adding 50px. I need something here that will set #navlogo to visible. Can anyone offer some assistance?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the css `display` property in your Javascript:

```
var logo = $('div#navlogo');
logo.css('display', 'block');
```

For example:  https://jsfiddle.net/gx25ospo/3/

Comment: Thanks david that worked perfectly. I like how the css properties are changed through the script too.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this style to your CSS at last:

```
.navbar-fixed-top #navlogo {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/gx25ospo/4/

```
.navbar-brand {
display: none;
}

.visible {
display: block;
}
```

JS

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= top) {

    nav.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    body.addClass('padding-fifty');
    $('.navbar-brand').addClass('visible');

} else {
    nav.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    body.removeClass('padding-fifty');
    $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('visible');
}
```